# Getting records between two dates for a certain amount of time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Say I have a table which looks like the following:

```
id | name  | date
1  | test1 | 2013-05-12 00:00:01
2  | test2 | 2013-05-13 00:00:01
3  | test3 | 2013-05-14 00:00:01
4  | test4 | 2013-05-15 00:00:01
5  | test5 | 2013-05-15 00:00:02
```

An example of what I am looking to do would be to go back through the records for the past 3 days and then I want to count how many records there are on each individual say.

So, for the 15th it would return 2, 14th 1, etc.

I know I can do the following to get a count between 2 dates (this would be for the 15th):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as recordCount FROM exampletable WHERE date >= STR_TO_DATE('130515', '%y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND date < STR_TO_DATE('130515', '%y%m%d')
```

However I am unsure how I would do it so I could get an array for the past 3 days.

I have an idea of how I could do it in PHP, having a for loop and then changing the first argument in `STR_TO_DATE` each time, but I am curious, is there a way I could do this using a SQL query only?

Comment: `... > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ...`

Comment: Use `GROUP BY DATE(date)`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are zero records for the 14th?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) recordCount 
  FROM exampletable 
 WHERE DATE(`date`) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURDATE()
 GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

*NOTE This query wont use any index on `date`*

Comment: Will you `GROUP BY` ignore **time** component?

Comment: @peterm That just returns a bunch of records where `recordCount` is 1. I'll play around with `GROUP BY` for a bit though. Thanks.

Comment: unless you expect records in the future you don't need between, just greater than 3 days ago

Comment: Note that the order of the result set is not guaranteed without an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'recordCount' FROM dbo.Table_1 
WHERE dt > DATEADD(dd,-3,GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd,dt)
```